# Angular 4 FormControl based on ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular4-forms

I have a autocomplete dropdown, and whatever I select is supposed to get added to an aray, and rendered one below other. I am pushing the selected object on select and using ngFor I am rendering the values plus an input field to specify quantity.

Issue is once I select one item, and it is rendered, I input some value in the textbox, and when I again select another product from autocomplete, the first value resets to 0. I am assuming that the name control is same which is creating the issue. But how to create new controls, since I am creating the formbuilder group during the load. Attached the image for clearer idea.
[image]

Comment: Please post your actual code, else no one can help.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming from how Angular handles the loops in HTML.

To avoid getting this kind of behavior, you need to change your code from this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of y">
  <span>{{x}}</span>
</ng-container>
```

To this

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let x of y; let i = index; trackBy:x.__ID"> // Use an unique identifier in place of __ID
  <span>{{x}}</span>
</ng-container>
```